# fragment and activity Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity

In activity I can associate layout xml as following

```
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
  setContentView(R.layout.main);
}
```

how in the `onCreate()` of `Fragment` class load an `Activity`?

I have fragement class as in the following

```
public class TestFragment extends Fragment {
  public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle saved) {
  }
}
```

Comment: there are many link you can refer this link ..... 1.[fragment class ](http://android-er.blogspot.com/search?q=on%20touch%20in%20android%20in%20imageview.)

Comment: Tutorial on fragments : http://www.vogella.com/articles/Android/article.html#fragments_tutorial

Answer (score 1):

If you want to inflate the xml layout inside the fragment you can do it easily with the LayoutInflater:

```
@Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.your_layout, container, false);
    }
```

For further information read the offical [Fragment Reference](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/fundamentals/fragments.html).